# How to check what checkbox is checked inside listview without using collections

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, checkbox

I would like to learn how to determine, which  checkbox is checkd inside the listview control, without using collections, if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Strawberry cake without strawberries?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "without using collections" part ?

Comment: I assume they meant without having the `ListView` data-bound to a backing collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the poster's use-case, but the obvious hack (which I don't endorse or recommend, but it's your code) is to have the checked and unchecked events update some value that you can inspect to determine if it's checked.